# How can I ensure that my function only acts on one element at a time? (Repost with more details)

Tags: javascript, function, animation

Is there a way to make sure that the **Right Leg** does not go up at the same time the **Left Leg** does every three seconds?

```
function RstartWalking() {
    setInterval(function() {
        walk();
    }, 1000);
}
function walk() {
    Rlegy = Rlegy - 7;
  Rinvy = Rinvy - 7;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (Rlegy > Rlegy - 8) {
            Rlegy = Rlegy + 7
          Rinvy = Rinvy +7
        }
    }, 500);
}
RstartWalking();
function LstartWalking() {
    setInterval(function() {
        Lwalk();
    }, 1500);
}
function Lwalk() {
    Llegy = Llegy - 7;
  Linvy = Linvy - 7
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (Llegy > Llegy - 8) {
            Llegy = Llegy + 7
          Linvy = Linvy +7
        }
    }, 500);
}
LstartWalking();
```

I'm looking for a function that does this: When the character is **not moving**, **both legs are down**. When the character **starts walking** the **left leg is up** and the **right leg is down**, then every *half second*, whichever leg was up goes down and whichever leg was down goes up, then when the character **stops moving**, *both legs go down again*.

Comment: What do you mean by "up" and "down"? Nothing in your code says up or down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your current code is doing with the 7s and 8s, or what it means to be "up" and "down". But this would be one way to manage leg state while walking, and controlling the stops and starts. It starts with both feet down, then starts walking with the left leg up, alternating legs every half second until stopping with both legs down.

```js
let rightLegIsDown = true
let leftLegIsDown = true
let stepping
function step() {
  rightLegIsDown = !rightLegIsDown
  leftLegIsDown = !leftLegIsDown
  logLegsStatus('step')
}
function start() {
  leftLegIsDown = false
  logLegsStatus('start')
  stepping = setInterval(() => step(), 500)
}
function stop() {
  clearInterval(stepping)
  rightLegIsDown = true
  leftLegIsDown = true
  logLegsStatus('stop')
}
function logLegsStatus(state) {
  console.log(`L${leftLegIsDown ? '⬇︎' : '⬆︎'} R${rightLegIsDown ? '⬇︎' : '⬆︎'}. (${state})`)
}
logLegsStatus('initial')
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', start)
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stop)
```

```html
<button type="button" id="start">Start Walking</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop Walking</button>
```